# RestorableBool vs bool in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

According to [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorableBool-class.html), ***RestorableBool*** class is a RestorableProperty that knows how to store and restore a bool. One example of RestorableBool is given by flutter itself in the [flutter gallery project](https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/banner).

The same result can be achieved by using simple boolean. [Click here](https://gist.github.com/Uvais-Mohammad/7c6da2dd29c988af3faac474bab97b44) to get the code of same screen using simple bool.

Is there any special benefits for **RestorableBool** over usual **bool** or is there any special context at which we have to use RestorableBool?

Anyone to help?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile operating systems fool you into thinking all the apps you have open are actually running. But they are not. The topmost is running, all others are killed. Their last screenshot is kept to uphold the illusion of being able to hold multiple apps open.

When you "switch apps", what happens is that the app that wasn't in the foreground is opened and it's state is restored from memory.

If you don't do anything, your app cannot handle this and will just start as if it was started from scratch.

In Flutter, the [Restoration Manager](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/RestorationManager-class.html) can help you store your state and restore your state. Other options are available, I think [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc) is probably useful if you are working with `bloc` patterns.

Comment: This should probably be marked as the accepted answer since it also gives context for the restoration manager etc.

Answer (score 2):

The example in your code doesn't do the same thing, well it does in your code, but it wouldn't in all cases.

The difference is that `RestorableBool` is reset to it's initial state, even if it is already in that state, meanwhile your code flips the bool to the opposite value.